# Extract String data using regular expression

Tags: regex

I m new to regular expressions. I have been trying to extract data from the string, for example:

```
Name AnotherName <#=Class.Name=#> Name 2 <#=AnotherClass.Name=#> Name3
```

I have tried this:

```
[a-zA-Z]+(?![^<#=]*\=#>)|(?![a-zA-Z])+[^<#=](.+?)=#>
```

which is just extracting "Name" properly. 
I'm looking to see the data extracted as:

```
Name
AnotherName
Class.Name
Name2
AnotherClass.Name
Name3
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, there's **much** easier than that, considering your test string:
Simply go for `[a-zA-Z0-9.]+`.

See a working live example [here on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rY3gN6/1).

Comment: No worries, glad to be of any help! Don't hesitate to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) if you're done with that question :)